# Extract audio from a video stream in python

Tags: python, video, audio

Is there an easy way to do that? I'm tempted to call ffmpeg, but it sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally no. But it can be done with [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/modules/gst-python.html).

Comment: TAE (https://github.com/tuna74/TunaAudioExtracter) does what you want, although that is coded with C using GStreamer. But it should not be difficult to port to PyGST.